# how to get parameters defined in jasper file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jasper-reports, ireport

I need to get the **parameters** defined in a **jasper file** so I can generate **inputs** depending of the type of these parameters to fill the report.
I'm working with `jasperreports-5.0.0`

Comment: do you mean to get the parameter value in jasper that was passed from java class

Comment: I mean the list of parameters defined in `.jasper` file, Thanks, I already found a solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(new File("report.jasper"));
JRParameter[] params = jasperReport.getParameters();

for(JRParameter param : params) {
  if(!param.isSystemDefined() && param.isForPrompting()){
     param.getName();
     param.getDescription();
     param.getDefaultValueExpression();
     param.getNestedTypeName();
  }
}
```